# What external JARS do I need to do an Android Multipart POST?

Tags: android

I am trying to do a Android Multipart POST, using the following code

```
   DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlString);

        File file = new File(pic);

        Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: setting up multipart entity");

        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: file length = " + file.length());
        Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: file exist = " + file.exists());

        try {
            mpEntity.addPart("datafile", new FileBody(file, "application/octet"));
            mpEntity.addPart("id", new StringBody("1"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: UnsupportedEncodingException");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: executing request: " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: request: " + httppost.getEntity().getContentType().toString());


        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: about to execute");
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: executed");
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: respose code: " + response.getStatusLine().toString());
            if (resEntity != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: " + EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
            }
            if (resEntity != null) {
                resEntity.consumeContent();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This crashes with an "java.lang.noclassdeffounderror org.apache.http.entity.mime.multipartentity" at

```
    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
```

My guess this is to do with the external Jars I am using. I have a Libs folder in my project and I have referenced the following files in my project build path.

httpclient-4.2.jar, httpcore-4.2.jar and httpmime-4.2.jar

Are these the correct versions? Or do I need more JARS ?

Answer (score 0):

In your Android project, create a directory named libs at the root of your project (next to src/, res/, etc.)

Locate the JAR file for the library you want to use and copy it into the libs/ directory.

[Setting Up a Project to Use a Library:](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html#SettingUp)

[More refer here:](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/10/changes-to-library-projects-in-android.html)