# loading so library failed

Tags: android

I'm try to load lib inside by that way:

```
getBundledStackLibFile():
        PackageInfo packageInfo = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), 0);
        if(packageInfo != null) {
            ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageInfo.applicationInfo;
            File f = getLibFileFromPackage(appInfo, libName, true);
            return f;
        }

        // This is the very last fallback method
        return new File(ctx.getFilesDir().getParent(), "lib" + File.separator + libName);
```

And then i'm using absolute path to using that .so file:

```
    File openslLib = getBundledStackLibFile(activityForUsing,
            "libpj_opensl_dev.so");

    audImp.setShared_lib_path(pjsua.pj_str_copy(openslLib.getAbsolutePath()));
```

But i have error:

10-01 10:53:11.209:  Cannot open : /data/data/com.myApp.android/lib/libpj_opensl_dev.so Cannot load library: link_image[1995]: failed to link libpj_opensl_dev.so

Here is unzipped ark file (necessary lib presented in all directories, screen short is just sample.

[image]

Comment: try changing the folder name lib to libs http://stackoverflow.com/a/12619865/1012284

Comment: @Padma Kumar i was read article, but it still not clear for me. In project folder i have correct directory name: libs. But in package is not, it is lib instead. Where is a setting in eclipse/project to change directory name?

Comment: the thing is your just storing as in lib folder here ...(), "lib" + File.separator + libName);

Comment: @Padma Kumar strange thing, but it again doesn't work, with "libs" + code too :( ay suggestions?